# how to add datas in taxonomy to post with wp_insert_post

Tags: php, customization, wp-insert-post

how to add datas in taxonomy  to post with wp_insert_post
this is my code but it is saved in my texonomy draft,why?
i have given post_type=publish.

```
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => 'test',
        'post_content'  => 'hello',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => $userdata->ID,
        'post_type' => 'Newpostlist',

       );

      $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
```

Comment: post_category expects an array of term IDs, not a string/term slug

Comment: @TomJNowell Should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

post_category expects an array of term IDs, not a string/term slug

```
$news_term = get_term_by('name', 'news', 'category');
$term_id = $news_term->term_id;
```

Now use the terms ID not its slug/name in your query args.

```
'post_category' => array($term_id),
```

Comment: An example would probably be helpful.

Comment: I've added a generic example